# ScrollView/ListView with fisheye effect

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview, fisheye

So as the title say, I wanna add some views in a scrollview(or listview), these views should have a fisheye effect when scrolled : the current view must have its default size and the other views must be scaled, here is an image of what I want:

[image]

I really don't know where to start so, any advice or proposition is appreciated, thanks

Edit : 
I found [this](https://github.com/raweng/Scroller) on iOS, and I wondered if there is a way to do it on Android

Comment: I think this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790238/fish-eye-effect-with-core-animation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685460/curving-warping-views-with-coreanimation-or-opengl-for-carousel-effect